# Python dataframe drop negative values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want drop negative values in some columns of the dataframe.
My code:

```
ad = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-1,2,3,4],'B':[5,-6,7,8],'C':[1,-2,0,1]})

    A   B   C
0   -1  5   1
1   2   -6  -2
2   3   7   0
3   4   8   -1
```

I want to drop negative value rows in A and B columns

Expected result:

```
ad = 
    A   B   C
1   3   7   0
2   4   8   -1
```

Present solution:

```
ad = ad[ad[['A','B']]>0]
     A       B       C
0   NaN     5.0     NaN
1   2.0     NaN     NaN
2   3.0     7.0     NaN
3   4.0     8.0     NaN

ad.dropna(how='any',inplace=True)
ad = []
```

Update:
I tried the below-accepted answer. Also, I figured out a numpy-based solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ad = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-1,2,3,4],'B':[5,-6,7,8],'C':[1,-2,0,1]})
print(ad[np.logical_and.reduce(ad[['A','B']]>0,axis=1)])
%timeit ad[np.logical_and.reduce(ad[['A','B']]>0,axis=1)]
   A  B  C
2  3  7  0
3  4  8  1
1000 loops, best of 5: 795 µs per loop

print(ad[(ad[['A','B']] > 0).all(1)])
%timeit ad[(ad[['A','B']] > 0).all(1)]

   A  B  C
2  3  7  0
3  4  8  1
1000 loops, best of 5: 979 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) you can check whether all elements in a row or column are true. You can use this in a filter on a subset of columns:

```
import pandas as pd
ad = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-1,2,3,4],'B':[5,-6,7,8],'C':[1,-2,0,-1]})
ad[(ad[['A','B']] > 0).all(1)]
```

Output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 8 | -1 |

Comment: is NumPy good here?

Comment: `pandas` already uses `numpy` under the hood

Comment: nice solution! Had to look twice; the `.all(1)` call transforms the df mask (with columns) into a series that operates across all cols.

Comment: This solution has the advantage to be parametrizable as we can select concerned columns by a single list.

Comment: Thanks for the neat solution. Also, I tried a numpy-based solution and updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For an exclusively Pandas solution, use `.loc` to filter out by boolean expressions.

The line of code:

```
ad.loc[(ad['A'] > 0) & (ad['B'] > 0)]
```

should filter out all rows corresponding to columns with negative `A` and negative `B`. If you want to reset the index as you did in your expected output, then just put `.reset_index(drop=True)` at the end of the above expression.

Using this on your example, here's what I get:

```
ad = pd.DataFrame({'A':[-1,2,3,4],'B':[5,-6,7,8],'C':[1,-2,0,1]})

ad.loc[(ad['A'] > 0) & (ad['B'] > 0)]
```

results in:

```
    A   B   C
2   3   7   0
3   4   8   1
```

Then doing

```
ad.loc[(ad['A'] > 0) & (ad['B'] > 0)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

results in:

```
    A   B   C
0   3   7   0
1   4   8   1
```